# Storing values of an array on a separate file as the array values changes

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am running some code which runs over 300k times. Each time this code runs, it returns up to 300k values. I am currently storing the results I get in an `ArrayList`:

```
List<List<Object>> thisList = new ArrayList<List<Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    thisList.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
}

for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    List<Object> result = someCode();
    for (Object obj : result) {
        thisList.get(obj.id).add(obj.value);
    }
}
```

In this code, everytime `obj` is obtained, it has a value `obj.id` which specifies the `index` in the `List` where `obj.value` has to be stored.

What would be the most efficient way to store the results elsewhere as the search continues? My code seems to stop working past iteration 400, most likely due to low memory issues. I have considered using a simple text document where each line represents a `List<Object>` but through some Googling, it seems there is no way to append to a specific line, and all suggestions seems to point towards overwriting the entire text document. I've never worked with databases before which is why I am trying to avoid that for now.

Would appreciate if someone can give me suggestions on what I could do.

Edit: Is there a method which does not use a database, where after each iteration of the outer `for loop`, the data can be stored?
For example, given a file which currently contains

```
List 0: obj.value1 obj.value2
List 1: obj.value1 obj.value4
...
List 300000: obj.value3 obj.value8
```

and result contains

```
{obj<1, 100>, obj<0, 3>, ...}
```

where each object is of the form `obj<id, value>`, the file becomes

```
List 0: obj.value1 obj.value2 obj.value3
List 1: obj.value1 obj.value4 obj.value100
...
List 300000: obj.value3 obj.value8
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Use map instead of List

Comment: Why the `Map<obj.id, obj.value>` does not fit?

Comment: Please provide the problem statement which you are trying to implement. After that we can try to provide the solution. As per your current code, you will definitely get the memory issue as you are creating the object of "new ArrayList<Object>()" 300K times.

Comment: (300K * 300K = 90B, so I could see how you might have memory constraint problems)

Comment: It's not clear how can the code be improved, because it's not clear what it's supposed to do. It's quite possible you can ignore plainly duplicates, or use different data structure that keeps tabs on a number of dupes but stores stats on how many dupes it has seen. But until more details are known, it's all unclear. At the end of the day, my first assumption is that the code is already doing what it's supposed to, in which case - increase the memory available to your app and be done with it.

Comment: Use a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store it in an XML file using JAXB api
Here is a link with a little tutorial on JAXB:
https://dzone.com/articles/using-jaxb-for-xml-with-java

Or you could also store it in a JSON file usin json-simple api
Here's another little tutorial:
https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-in-java/

These are the links to download JAXB and json-simple from maven:
JAXB: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
json-simple: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple

Hope it'll be useful to you